# How can I route a path which has '?' character in it in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend

For example in browser we send /controller/test?value=2 but I want to route this at an endpoint? I have another endpoint /controller/test which captures even the requests made to this route

Answer (score 1):

That's a query string.

You can use `@Query` decorator in the function parameter

```js
@Get('/path')
async find(@Query() query) {
  console.log(query);
}
```

[More info](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers)

Comment: The issue is not that I can get the value or not. The issue is apparently I have to implement 2 end points which are /controller/test?value=2  and /controller/test but if I use the 2nd one all requests are redirected there. Any clue what should be my path to catch this?

Comment: You can't have endpoints like that. There are the same endpoints and only the last registered one will be used. The query string difference will not treat it as an independent endpoint.

Comment: Why u need such a difference? U can make one if statement and differentiate logic there

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, it seems like your route `/controller/test` accepts a query parameter `value`. Regardless of whether or not you query that route with the query parameter `value`, all requests will hit your route controller at `controller/test`.

In other words, your server treats

GET `/controller/test` as a request to `/controller/test` as a request with `value: undefined`

and

GET `/controller/test?value=2` as a request to `/controller/test` as a request with `value: 2`

Therefore, your controller should look something like (assuming you're using typescript)

```js
  interface ControllerQuery {
    value?: number
  }

  @Get('/controller/path')
  async controller( @Query query: ControllerQuery ) { 
    if (query.value) {
      console.log(query.value);
    } else {
      console.log('No value provided, now what?');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said above, query params are not filtered by route. But you could do something like this, which would be more restful as well. That or having a `search` endpoint.

```
@Get('/path')
async without() {
  console.log('without param');
}

@Get('/path/:value')
async find(@Param('value') value: string,) {
  console.log(value);
}

@Get('/path/search')
async search(@Query() query) {
  console.log(query);
}
```